# Getting the selected rows' values in datagridview and adding them up

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, label

[image]

I am making a booking winsform application now. When a user chooses any number of rows, there will be a column called rental price that each row is under. Then the value of this cell under the column called rental price will be gotten and add up and display to the total cost label text.**But the problem is the total cost is not displaying.** Here is my code:

```
private void Payment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   NameOfUser.Text = UserAccounts[0].Name;
   EmailOfUser.Text = UserAccounts[0].Email;
   PaymentType.Text = UserAccounts[0].PaymentType;        
   double totalCost = 0;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in b1.DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
   {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            totalCost += (double)dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value;
        }
        index++; 
   }

   TotalCost.Text = Convert.ToString(totalCost);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions? have you gone through break points

Comment: @un-lucky , no errors / exceptions. Added BreakPoints but they did not went thru.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the Mistake is in the looping, As of now you are iterating the rows in the `SelectedRows` and by using the inner loop you again looping through the cells of each row But taking values with respect to the actual grid instead for the cell. You can make this simple as you wanted to iterate through the selected rows and need to sums the value of `.Cells[4]` in each row. for that you have to do something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in b1.DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
   string value = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
   double currentCellValue = 0.0;  
   if(double.TryParse(value , out currentCellValue)
   { 
      totalCost += currentCellValue;
   }
 }
TotalCost.Text = totalCost .ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem!! I upvoted it but it wont be displayed in public because my reputation is less than 15. Sorry!

Comment: Haha just nice, my reputation became 15. Upvoted it! thank you very much!!!

Comment: Thanks You too! Happy Coding too!!:)